# Does "All" imply one or more?

Tags: meaning

Does *all* imply that there is one or more of something?

- Does the statement "all of the books are red" imply there is at least one red book?
- Could there be zero books and the statement still be factually correct?
- Is it inherently ambiguous?

Not sure if this is an English question or more of a math or logic question.

Comment: For logic, see https://iep.utm.edu/sqr-opp/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It certainly implies that there are at least two books (because it's plural), although logically and semantically speaking, it is possible for there to be no books at all (or just one).

It's not ambiguous, unless either:

- the person making the statement has already made it clear, or makes it clear immediately afterwards, that he/she doesn't know if there are any books, but if there were, they would be red, or
- it is deliberately said in a "can you figure out the trick in this problem?" or similar method in an attempt to confuse someone.

Comment: +1, although technically you use the plural also with zero... "There are zero red books". :)

Comment: @nico: *cough* [None of our aircraft is missing](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/comment/letters/3589220/Personal-opinion.html) *cough*

Comment: @nico, technically you use i.e. the plural is applied to the set; "red books" is plural - the cardinality does not matter.

Comment: @Rhodri: *none* takes the singular, *zero* the plural. It just works like that... :). @Unreason: cardinality matters, as 1 is used with the singular, the other numbers with the plural.

Comment: @Unreason: sure, *red books* is plural, but how do you choose to use the plural rather then the singular? By looking at cardinality.

Answer (score 6):

It would depend on the context.

A logician or computer programmer would probably not infer that there are a non-zero number of books. A computer programmer would probably want to know if there can be zero or one books (and accept any of the possible answers as sensible).

In normal speech, it tends to imply that there are at least two books - it would be surprising if there were fewer than two, but you couldn't complain that the statement was strictly inaccurate.

Comment: I like saying that all the meat I eat is from intentionally tortured animals when animal rights activists are begging me for a donation on the streets (I'm a vegetarian). They usually leave me in peace afterwards. :)

Comment: And for mathematicians, it's not just that "probably" zero or none is a possibility, anyone who learns mathematics is going to learn very soon that it's a possibility, and probably the hard way, by forgetting about it and not being able to solve a problem because of it.

Answer (score 4):

Depending on context, I could say "I want you to hand over all your books" without knowing whether there were zero, one or more books. But It wouldn't make sense to say "all the books were red" if no books were handed over :-)

Answer (score -1):

In terms of English usage, it would be confusing to say that all of your books were red if you had zero books. If you have no books, it's not possible to describe the colour of something that doesn't exist.

In fact, saying that all of your books are red implies 3 or more books in English usage, because you can't refer to "all one of those books" nor can you refer to "all two of those books." English has a special word for "all two." You have to say "both of those books."

Comment: Actually, describing an empty set (of books) would [hold vacuously.](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuous_truth)

Comment: If this were a math or logic question, yes, it holds vacuously, but there was a question of English usage. In actual natural language, a person would never say "all my books are red" when there were no books, unless the speaker were trying to trick the listener. There is a very strong implication that "all" refers to three or more things. The question was asking about what is implied, not what is logically true.

Comment: If you think that's the case, please edit your answer to include a source to support that. For more information on vacuous truth in a more philosophic sense, please consider this question on the [philosophy SE](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/q/43378/32905).

Comment: @JJJ Neil Wick's argument is sound in the real world. The situation with the absent cell phones relates to Schroedinger's cat as they can be on and off at the same time. This moves us so far from the real world of linguistics that it can be dismissed in this forum.

Answer (score -3):

> Does all imply that there is one or more of something?

No. All (the whole of) the tool is hot. / All the food is edible / All the items are edible.

> Does the statement "all of the books are red" imply there is at least one red book?

No. The plural "books" implies that there are three or more books - **all** states that the red books are without exception.

> Could there be zero books and the statement still be factually correct?

No. The absence of books cannot have a colour.

> Is it inherently ambiguous?

No.

Comment: Needs reference.

Comment: @GEdgar I assume you are not disputing that "books" is the plural of "book" or that "The absence of books cannot have a colour." -- This leaves *No. All (the whole of) the tool is hot. / All the food is edible / All the items are edible.* which is so basic for EL&U that I think we can accept this *ab intio.* ("All the world's a stage" W. Shakespeare).

Comment: One can't help wondering on what ground do you disagree with the well balanced answer by Marcin, in particular, with what that answer says about how the matter would be treated in the context of logic and programming (as distinct from everyday conversation).

Comment: @jsw29. The question is "Does **all** imply that there is one or more? It implies neither. The question does not extend itself to logic and programming and therefore it is not necessary to address these areas, particularly not in detail or this forum.